# Computing a rotation matrix given an axis vector and angle

Tags: matrices

I am reading [Kuipers'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691102988) book, I am struggling with following problem

> Consider an **XYZ** coordinate frame, with the vector $v_0 = (1,1,1)$
>   through an angle $\phi = 2\pi/3$. It is geometrically clear that such
>   a rotation results in a new frame in which the **new x-axis**
>   coincides with **former Y-axis**, the **new y-axis** coincides with
>   the **former Z-axis**, and the **new z-axis** coincides with the
>   **initial X-axis**.
>
> $(1,0,0) \rightarrow (0,0,1)$
>
> $(0,1,0) \rightarrow (1,0,0)$
>
> $(0,1,0) \rightarrow (0,1,0)$

My question is, could you figure out without any calculations, just by drawing lets say, deduce that $(1,0,0)$ will transform to $(0,0,1)$?, because the author says, *"It is **geometrically clear** that such a rotation results in a new frame ..."* In my case, I have to calculate the rotation matrix, write some code and verified numerically that indeed $(1,0,0)$ will transform to $(0,0,1)$ but I can't imagine in my head how each rotation transform the vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is referring to the rotation through an angle $2\pi/3$ about the vector $v_0$ as what he talks about in section 3.5.1 on page 56. Therefore, if we draw this image
[image] 
And look at it in the opposite direction of $v_0$, which is
[image] 
you can see that a $2\pi/3$ rotation about $v_0$ is a rotation of the equilateral triangle (look at the vertices). This will result in the transforms you quoted.

Comment: Hi Yourong Zang, sorry my ignorance, i know that this question is silly to answer, but how do you can assure that these tree vectors form an equilateral triangle in the plane perpendicular to the axis vector?

Comment: @user2321651 If I understand your question correctly, you are asking for how to know that points $A, B, C$ form an equilateral triangle on the plane they lie on. Is that right?

Comment: @user2321651 In my opinion, to geometrically see this without further rigorous proofs, you can connect the point which $v_0$ is pointing at, $(1,1,1)$ and $A, B, C$ respectively. Then you will be able to see that there are three congruent triangles and thus $A, B, C$ form an equilateral triangle. All these can be done geometrically. (I believe that you are referring to vectors $\left<(0,0,0), A\right>$, $\left<(0,0,0), B\right>$, $\left<(0,0,0), C\right>$ in your comment)

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks for your help mister.

Comment: @user2321651 You are welcome